# How long does a mysql_connect stay open?

Tags: php, mysql, command-line-interface

I have a CLI script which when you first start it:

```
function __construct(){$this->connectToDatabase();}
protected function connectToDatabase(){
    try{
        $this->databaseName = $this->dbname;
        $this->posName = $this->posName;
        $this->vlog = $this->vlogName;
        $this->database = mysql_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        mysql_select_db($this->databaseName, $this->database);
    }
    catch(Exception $e){
        $this->console($e);
    }
}
```

This CLI script can stay running for days. How do i keep the mysql connection open? or before each mysql_query do i have to check if the connection is still open?

This is the error im getting:

> MySQL Error: MySQL server has gone away

Comment: Do you have any problems with this? The connection should stay open (unless you have some setting that limits the time a connection can be open on your server).

Comment: yes i have problems. basically this is a 'server' cli that accepts websocket connections. for some reason when i tryed to connect a day latr i got the `MySQL Error: MySQL server has gone away` error

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check this : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-set-no-timeout-to-mysql

In particular, it is stated:

> The server timed out and closed the
>   connection. By default, the server
>   closes the connection after 8 hours or
>   28800 seconds if nothing has happened.
>   You can change the time limit by
>   setting the **wait_timeout** variable when
>   you start mysqld via your server’s
>   **/etc/my.cnf** [...]

Comment: This is a server that has to be running at least 12 hours of the day. i cant have it time out during business hours

Comment: i dont see wait_timeout in the my.cnf file

Comment: If you don't see wait_timeout, just add it.
BTW, for which reason "This CLI script can stay running for days." ?

Comment: i said it 'can' stay running for days, doesnt mean it will in the future. i have to add a close mechanism to it that it closes if it reaches the next day ^_^

Comment: It's in seconds. Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout

Comment: BTW I was just asking why your script could run for hours. Long queries ?

Comment: lol no its not long queries. its a websocket server. clients could be connecting and asking for information at any point in the day

Comment: @frosty - that link u gave is talking about `mysql_pconnect` i am using `mysql_connect` how are they different?

Comment: its a websocket server => Ok. Then reopening the MySQL connection should be necessary, as you pointed out.
For difference between `mysql_pconnect` and `mysql_connect`, check the PHP manual (`mysql_pconnect` description): http://fr2.php.net/mysql_pconnect

Comment: hmmmm which type of mysql connection should i use then for a websocket server?

Comment: A little more reading... http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php I don't have a clear answer yet, I'm interested too! :)

Comment: Persistent connections seem to be interesting when the connections/disconnections are very frequent (e.g. website hosted by Apache under heavy load, using PHP scripts connecting/disconnecting frequently to MySQL). In your case, you open the MySQL connection once, and your PHP script waits. Then it's already nearly the same result as using a "persistent connection". So you can simply stick with `mysql_connect` IMO.

Comment: lol ok. now i just got to make it so it doesnt disconnect on me

Comment: Update
http://techgurulive.com/how-to-solve-mysql-server-has-gone-away-or-lost-connection-to-server-during-query-fix/