# How long PDO hold mysql connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Simple question. How long PDO hold connection? Is there any parametr to set that? Im asking because im using pdo mysql connection in socket server and after some time i think pdo lose connection, is possible?

Comment: till you don't close connection or server stoped.

Comment: that depends on how the server ins configured. but the easiest way would be to simply test it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long does a mysql\_connect stay open?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5397776/how-long-does-a-mysql-connect-stay-open)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a connect timeout with PDO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21403082/setting-a-connect-timeout-with-pdo)

Answer (score 0):

At standard configuration the connection will be opened forever and will be normally closed by server timeout `wait_timeout`.

Answer (score 0):

The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object.

To close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are deleted—you do this by assigning null to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close the connection when your script ends.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php